# Flutter build apk crashes on startup even if all package names are the same

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Is there any way to isolate this problem? Every time I tried to install my build apk on any device, it keeps crashing but on debug mode it works fine. I don't get any error when running `flutter build apk` aside from after installing it and opening it immediately crashes. Also the app is not yet signed just wanna test it on different mobiles using a generated apk

What I tried so far:

> 1. Change all package names to same in `AndroidManifest.xml` in **app/src** and the folders with xmls there.
> 2. Change package names to the one I've used in AndroidManifest in build.gradle
> 3. Even changed the package name in **google-services.json** since I'm using Firebase

In case it is needed heres my pubspec.yaml

```
name: vmembershipofficial
description: V Membership App

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.9
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  firebase_database: ^3.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_bloc: ^3.1.0
  bloc_pattern: ^2.3.2
  video_player: ^0.10.5+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  assets:
   - assets/images/

  fonts:
    # - family: Schyler
    #   fonts:
    #     - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
    #     - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
    #       style: italic
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Black.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Blackitalic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Bolditalic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-italic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Light.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Lightitalic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Thin.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Lato-Thinitalic.ttf
```

Comment: You can run flutter run --release to run the app as release on the device and track all the logs as in the debug mode

Comment: run `adb logcat` just after crash to get actual logs. May it helps.

Comment: You can run android module separately through android studio and can see logcat as you do for normal android app.

Comment: Hi guys,  check my answer I fixed it already thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. Out of nowhere I think of using `flutter pub upgrade` and it works. I saw a similar question here in Stack but it doesn't work for me I will just comment my answer on that question to help others as well.

Comment: Yes, this helped me to fix the crash. This and downgrading flutter sdk from 1.22.5/.6 to 1.22.4